# Python os.system Appending to file cuts of first letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

it's my first post on here, so I hope, I won't ask in a too bad way.

I recently started teaching myself python(3) and found a lot of solutions to my problems on this website, but now I'm stuck on a problem without solution.
When i want to write the output of a system command into a file it cuts off the first lines of it, which i grepped.

```
file.write("Mailserver: \n \n")
os.system("dig" + " " + domain + " " + "MX | grep MX >> %s" % filename)
```

If I take the example of google.com I end up with this being put in my file:

```
le.com.
google.com.     600 IN  MX  50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     600 IN  MX  30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     600 IN  MX  20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     600 IN  MX  40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

while the output should be

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P1-1-Debian <<>> google.com MX
;google.com.            IN  MX
google.com.     262 IN  MX  40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     262 IN  MX  10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     262 IN  MX  20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     262 IN  MX  30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com.     262 IN  MX  50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

I also had my script run the following to make sure it greps the proper stuff:

```
file.write("Mailserver: \n \n")
os.system("dig" + " " + domain + " " + "MX | grep MX >> %s" % filename) 
os.system("dig" + " " + domain + " " + "MX | grep MX")
```

I added the last line to print out the result of the dig, which gave out a proper result, while the above line still only gave the cut text into the file i defined.

Does anyone have a solution or idea to this? I'm kind of stuck with my issue.

Comment: What was the mode that you open `file` with?? Was it `w` or `a`??

Comment: file = open('%s' % filename, 'w+') @anwarvic

Comment: use `a` instead of`w+` :)

Comment: Did it, now it adds the entire text, but puts it at the start of the file. Is there any way i can have it put to the end of the file instead?

Comment: Could you post the whole code, please?

Comment: os.system("dig" + " " + domain + " " + "MX | grep MX >> %s" % filename) 

This adds itself to the start of the created file

Comment: So when i used w+ it went to the end, being cut off. When i use a it goes to the start but without being cut off.

Comment: could you please delete file and then try the code again. The `a` model means "append" which means it takes the output and append it at the end of the existing file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, I believe your problem happens because you execute a command using `os.system` to write into an **open** file. So, you need to close the file before running the command.

So, instead of

```
file.write("Mailserver: \n \n")
os.system("dig" + " " + domain + " " + "MX | grep MX >> %s" % filename)
```

You need to make it:

```
file.write("Mailserver: \n \n")
file.close() #close the file
os.system("dig" + " " + domain + " " + "MX | grep MX >> %s" % filename)
file = open('%s' % filename, 'a') #open it again
```

Comment: thanks :) Got a few thousand lines to go, but I really enjoy python.